# How do I set a string property of a struct?

Tags: c, struct

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyData {
    int id;
    char msg[255];
};

int main ( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {
    struct MyData item; 
    item.id = 3;
    item.msg = "something else";
    printf("Msg: %d", item.msg);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error of incompatible types in assignment on the line:
item.msg = "something else";

I have no worries setting the id property, but I can't figure out how to set the string property "msg". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: For reference...since the string is a literal, as of C99 you can say `struct MyData item = { 3, "something" };  item = (struct MyData) { 3, "something else" };`.  Only works with array and string literals, though, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strncpy()` to copy the string into the character buffer. Don't forget to assign `\0` to the last element just in case.

Comment: Note that I personally don't like `strncpy()` over `strcpy()` because 1) it writes to every byte in the destination buffer, filling it with zeros at the end, and 2) if the destination is smaller than source, one must manually write `0` at the end, and in this case, a better solution most of the time is to have a larger destination buffer to begin with.

Comment: strlcpy is your friend. Google it.

Comment: I know about `strlcpy()`, but it's not ANSI/ISO C.  It's not even POSIX.

Comment: "%d" is for integers. "%s" is for strings (char*'s), so take care when you use printf.

Comment: if dest is 256 bytes: `sprintf (dest,"%.255s",data);` is portable and has no gotchas.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the name of an array in a value context is the same as a pointer.  That is, if I have an "array of type `T`", then it is the same as "pointer to type `T`" in a value context.  What is a value context?  It is basically whenever the *value* of the object is used.  This happens when you pass the name of the object to a function, use the name on the right hand side of an assignment, etc.  But in the case above, on the LHS of the expression, it is not used in a value context but "object context", because you are not "reading" the value of the array object, you are assigning to it.

In other words, if you had a pointer (`char *msg;`), you could say `msg = "something else";`, and it would work, because you are setting the pointer `msg` to point to the location that contains the (read-only) string `"something else"`.  When you have `char msg[255];`, you can't say `msg = "something else";` because `msg` already has a fixed space allocated to it, and it does not make sense to say "this space now points to *another* space which contains my string".  The best thing you can do  now is to copy the string from the other location in the location used by `msg`.  `msg` is used in an *object context* here, and thus doesn't "decay" to a pointer.

For an excellent explanation of the difference, please see [C for Smarties: Analyzing expressions](http://web.torek.net/torek/c/expr.html#therule).

The solution is to either make `msg` a pointer (if your strings are all known at compile-time, or if you don't mind dynamically allocating memory), or to use `strcpy()`/`strncpy()` (I personally don't like `strncpy()` because it might not null-terminate the destination).

Answer (score 0):

try using strcpy (3); since strings are not strings per se but arrays of char - you may not (usually) access a `string' in such a manner.

Cheers
~knubbze