# How to use strings with structs in C?

Tags: c

I have seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988186/how-do-i-set-a-string-property-of-a-struct) but it is terribly uninformative for newbie's like myself and still can't manage to get it to work. I am trying to declare a member of the struct called "name" that takes a string value and then trying to figure out how to get that value and print it. Every way I have tried produces an error...

```
typedef struct {
    float height;
    int weight;
    char name[];
} Person;


void calculateBMI(Person x) {
    //printf will go here here
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Person Michael;
    Michael.height = 62.0;
    Michael.weight = 168;
    Michael.name[] "Michael";

    Person Steve;
    Steve.height = 50.4;
    Steve.weight = 190;
    Steve.name = "Steven";

    calculateBMI(Michael);
    calculateBMI(Steve);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the length of the char array, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float height;
    int weight;
    char name[30];
} Person;
```

Then you use strcpy to populate it:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Person Michael;
    Michael.height = 62.0;
    Michael.weight = 168;
    strcpy(Michael.name, "Michael");

    Person Steve;
    Steve.height = 50.4;
    Steve.weight = 190;
    strcpy(Steve.name, "Steven");

    calculateBMI(Michael);
    calculateBMI(Steve);
}
```

This solution will be the cleanest in all the common cases as you are allocating the space into the stack when you declare a new variable of type `Person` . In most complex scenarios you don't know the size of the char array and maybe you need to keep it as small as possible. In those case you can use a `malloc` solution.
Remember that everytime you are using `malloc` youy have to remember to `free` the allocated space when you are done with the data.

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me. But I wonder why I get the error, 'Implicitly declaring library function 'strcpy' with type 'char*(char*, const char *)''

Comment: you should #include <string.h>

Comment: "You have to specify the length of the char array" is incorrect.  "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member."  C11dr §6.7.2.1 18.

Answer (score 1):

You can to declare the name member as `char *` and allocate space to copy the string into it

```
typedef struct {
    float height;
    int weight;
    char *name;
} Person;


size_t length;
const char *name = "Michael";


length       = strlen(name);
Michael.name = malloc(1 + length);

if (Michael.name != NULL)
    strcpy(Michael.name, name);
```

and then when you are done using the `struct`, don't forget to `free`

```
free(Michael.name);
```

or do as **HAL9000** suggests, but this solution wont work for longer strings.

You could simplify this process by creating a helper function like

```
char *dupstr(const char *src)
{
    char   *dst;
    size_t  length;

    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;
    length = strlen(src);
    dst    = malloc(1 + length);
    if (dst == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(dst, src);
    return dst;
}
```

and then

```
typedef struct {
    float height;
    int weight;
    char *name;
} Person;

Michael.name = dupstr("Michael");
```

but you will also need to call `free` after finished using the struct.

Comment: These seems like a very lengthy route, no?

Comment: @MichaelRader Perhaps, but it's the dynamic way of doing it, and eventually you will have to learn how to deal with it, you must learn.

Comment: strdup will do the length, malloc and copy for you http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html

Comment: @pm100 `strdup` is not standard, but it's not that hard to write one.

Comment: strdup is a posix standard

Comment: @pm100 but not a c standard, and very often people posting questions are using `MS Windows` so no `strdup` available for them.

Comment: It's just that I don't currently understand this form. The 'size_t' and 'malloc' is something new to me. Thanks (and an upvote) but the other answer is better suited for me right now.

Comment: @iharob I'm definitely not on windows. ;)

Comment: @MichaelRader I understand, but keep in mind that you should read about this things.

Comment: no c programmer can say 'I dont know malloc'. malloc (and understanding it) is what essentially distinguishes C from perl, java, ....

Comment: I'm not a C programmer. I'm coming from JavaScript and just now learning C/Objective-C.

Comment: @pm100 you are totally right, and that's why I don't think anyone would benefit from avoiding to learn how to use it.

Comment: Note: Consider `return memcpy(dst, src, length+1)` instead of `strcpy(dst, src); return dst;`.  IMO: faster/tighter.  BTW: this `dupstr()` handles `src== NULL`.  `strdup()` does not always do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    float height;
    int weight;
    char name[];
} Person;
```

this struct has no size declared for the name this means that when you create the struct you must also create space for the name .

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Person *Michael=malloc(sizeof(Person)+strlen("Michael")+1);
    if(!Michael)return 1;
    Michael->height = 62.0;
    Michael->weight = 168;
    strcpy(Michael->name,"Michael");

    calculateBMI(Michael);
    free(Michael);
}
```

Comment: @HAL9000 flexible array members like `Person.name` are an addition of C99 intended to be used like in this answer, although in a real implementation it would be necessary to add another field with the size of `name`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: @Fernando, thank you I'm learning it but I'll never use it in all my life :-)

Comment: @HAL9000 it has a typo in `sizeof(person)`, it needs to include some headers like `string.h` and `stdlib.h`, and `calculateBMI()` isn't defined. Fixing those it compiles with `gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c`. PD: I don't think I ever used this feature :)

Comment: This really is an up-to-date way of doing things.  (note  `sizeof(person)` to `sizeof(Person)`)

Comment: @Fernando Do not agree with "necessary to add another field with the size of name".  Such a field may help with some other functionality, but is not _necessary_.

Comment: You are right @chux it may be convenient to copy the structure, but given the last field is a `\0` terminated string it is not necessary as you can calculate the size of the structure.